# months_between query error in JDBC query not getting any output or even Error

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

```
public class AgeCheck {


    static String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL" ; 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         PreparedStatement p;

            try {
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,"surya","surya");
                System.out.println("Connection success");
                p = con.prepareStatement("select months_between(doj,dob) from agecheck");


                ResultSet r =  p.executeQuery();
                while(r.next()){
                    System.out.println(r.getInt(1));
                }


                con.close();

            }catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
}
```

Help me out i'm getting nothing as output

whats wrong in Retrieving data in  Result Set

SQL Table details

[image: SQL Table Data]

Comment: table please with some example data

Comment: Added Table image link - @VikramSingh

Comment: with my system it is working fine

Comment: did you commit the table after inserting data into table?

Comment: Thanks @VikramSingh i forgot to commit.

Comment: i'm sorry i can't see the image, can you tell me what type of **doj** and **dob** ? String or Date?